# Light box displaying 2 images, thumbnail the issue?

Tags: html, css, light, box

I have a lightbox setup on my site and well I've got an unordered list and the images are displayed in a list item. I've got an href linking to the full size image then my lightbox code and then an img src with a thumbnail image. Why is my lightbox displaying 2 images and not the one.
I think it's displaying my thumbnail and the full size image but I'm not sure. When I click the image, it says 1-2. If you press the next button it shows the same image.

A peek at the code below. I expect it to be fairly simple but I'm learning..

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <a href="images/respectyourelders-full.png" 
       data-lightbox="recentwork"
       data-title="This design was made for an apparel company called VolkWear Clothing.">
         <img src="images/car1.png" alt="Respect your Elders Illustration" title="Respect your Elders Illustration" />
     </a>
```

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with the code you have posted. A link to the offending website would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Vector, the site isn't live. It's all local host currently.  Should I link more of my code to help out more?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is because you used **data-lightbox="recentwork"** for more than one hyperlink. Be sure to check it carefully.

Comment: I'm not too sure what I should do then. Once I removed the data-lightbox="recent work", the image would open in the same window causing you to hit the back button to get back to the site.

This is what I was using as a guide for the lightbox. 
If you have a group of related images that you would like to combine into a set, use the same data-lightbox attribute value for all of the images. 

<a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>
 <a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #3</a>
 <a href="img/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #4</a>

Comment: per lightbox instructions.. If you have a group of related images that you would like to combine into a set, use the same data-lightbox attribute value for all of the images. For example:
`<a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>
 <a href="img/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #3</a>
 <a href="img/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #4</a>` thats why I had the data-lightbox="recent work" it didn't solve the 2 images being the same, I have "4" images total displaying where 2 are just duplicates. example image 1 is the same as image 3 and 2 is same as 4